# Euler equation, Pressure and Helmholtz Free Energy

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I tried to obtain the pressure expression by an alternative route.
Given $$A=U-TS=-\beta^{-1}\ln{Z}$$ and using Euler equation $$U=TS-PV$$ I get $$A=-PV$$
Simply by substitution, I get $$P=\frac{\beta^{-1}\ln{Z}}{V}$$  This is different from what I know $$P=\beta^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial \ln{Z}}{\partial V}\right)_T$$ Did I do something wrong here? I am aware of other routes to get to this expression.  However, I can not understand why this approach does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not writing the general equations. The most general ones are in the differential form:

$$ dA = dU - TdS $$

and from the first principle

$$ dU = TdS - PdV $$

Hence you have:

$$ dA = - PdV $$

This means

$$ P = - \frac{\partial A}{\partial V} = \beta^{-1}\frac{\partial \log{Z}}{\partial V}$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Yes, I know that this way of obtaining the equation is correct, but I still do not see why the above approach does not work.  I must be missing something fundamental here.  The Euler equation uses an extensive property of E.  Other than the definition of A, I did not assume anything.

Comment: The correct euler equation is $E-TS+PV=\mu N$. You seem to be assuming that the chemical potential $\mu=0$.